# Headers not being set using curl_setopt PHP

Tags: php, curl, tcpdump, basic-authentication

I'm using curl_setopt to set the header in my request.
Specifically, I want to make it so the header includes what kind of authorization is being used.

```
  // Define headers to use
  $header = array(
         'HTTP/1.1',
         'Content-type: text/plain',
         'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password")
  );

// Below I prepare the request

$ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);;
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); // set custom header
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

 $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

 if (curl_errno($ch)) {
     echo 'CURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
 }

 $result=curl_exec ($ch);

 echo $result;

 curl_close ($ch);
```

My use case is running tcpdump to analyze the header (by finding the string "Authorization: Basic" and thus getting the base64 encoding of username:password

Thus when this php program sends out this request to $URL (by loading this program's page), TCP Dump should detect the base64 encoding that uis being sent out, right?

However, tcpdump doesn't pickup the header and I think it's because I'm not setting the headers correctly.

Comment: asking for CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE before curl_exec() makes no sense, and you're likely getting garbage data

Comment: can you check what this code returns? it might give you some clues! $headers=array();$cookies=array();$debugInfo='';$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch, $url,$headers,$cookies, $debugInfo);var_dump($headers,$cookies,$debugInfo,$html); 

https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the curl request.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//remember to close the connection too
curl_close($ch).
```

If you do not call [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php), you are never sending the request, and therefore never sending the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK to me. However, you don't need the Authorization header when using CURLOPT_USERPWD since it will override any existing Authorizations headers. in the headers array.

A suggestion is to debug you curl request by sending it to http://requestb.in.

Answer (score 0):

The way you set HTTP headers is right.
Did you forget to call `curl_exec($ch);` after all that?

Answer (score 0):

you have to run curl_exec first:

```
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
```

and then check the status code:

```
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'CURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```